# Validation fails on ModelForm

Tags: django, modelform

**NOTE/UPDATE:** This issue was caused by spelling error :(

---

Hi I'm trying to teach my self Django while making a small Task management app.

I have a Model

```
class Task(models.Model):
    track = models.ForeignKey(Track, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=265, blank=True)
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

and related ModelForm

```
class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ['track', 'title', 'description', 'done']
```

When form is posted taskForm.is_valid() is returning False. 
This is post_task method:

```
def post_task(request):
    form = TaskForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(commit=True)
    else:
        print(form.errors)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

and the form tag on the page:

```
     <form action="post_url" mehod="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ task_form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Add"/>
     </form>
```

**Even though I've filled in all the data I'm getting validation error**, this is the console print:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>track<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>title<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

All values have been passed in the request:

```
[23/Apr/2017 12:34:38] "GET /post_url/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=VqUx3EM9yGFzS88kYRtTWtniaCV8ZukxymylPILlxHBohtfEyhD3epOKOjKNIVCU&track=1&title=testTitle&description=testDescription HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you're doing your request as POST? , it appears that is a GET.

Comment: Side note: You don't need to pass `commit=True` to `form.save()`, that's the default.

Comment: Another side note: Try to use the `{% url %}` template tag in the `action` attribute, or leave it blank to send the data to the same page.

Comment: Thanks all, It was a spelling error. I feel I should delete the question, since it will not be very helpful to other people?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a spelling mistake occurs there `mehod`

```
<form action="post_url" mehod="post">
```

change this to

```
<form action="post_url" method="post">
```

Comment: damn, you are right I can't imagine how I missed this. And it should have been obvious from the console that I'm sending GET and not POST